# How can I sort a nested list based on numeric values?

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list which looks like this:

```
raw =  
[[(8, 0.44880571384598744), (17, 0.0403732344197908), 
(13, 0.03796821181062157), (1, 0.03777621092166489), 
(3, 0.02907007584458954), (5, 0.027577126778171947)], 
[(6, 0.24885153810452418), (13, 0.11945937235381485), 
(1, 0.07967490411502279), (7, 0.059837943219436064), 
(11, 0.054917316390175455), (3, 0.05439173103552319), 
(12, 0.042902668032641526), (2, 0.04067120278932331)]]
```

I want to sort the nested list based on the int at index[0] of every sublist.

But when I try this:

```
sortraw = []
for line in raw:
    k = sorted(line[0])
    sortraw.append(k)
```

The lists get sorted by the float value of every sublist and nested list vanishes.

My desired result would be look like this:

```
[[(1, 0.03777621092166489), (3, 0.02907007584458954), 
(5, 0.027577126778171947), (8, 0.44880571384598744),
(13, 0.03796821181062157), (17, 0.0403732344197908)], 
[(1, 0.07967490411502279), (2, 0.04067120278932331), 
(3, 0.05439173103552319), (6, 0.24885153810452418),
(7, 0.059837943219436064), (11, 0.054917316390175455),  
(12, 0.042902668032641526), (13, 0.11945937235381485)]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `sorted(line[0])` -> `sorted(line, key=line[0])` - you want to keep the whole list (`line`) but sort it by the first element (key)

Comment: @h4z3 I'm not sure what you are saying, your key (`key=line[0]`)  is not a defined function or a `lambda`

Comment: @jamylak Ah, yes, that was a quick comment, but the idea should be clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
raw = [[(8, 0.44880571384598744), (17, 0.0403732344197908), 
... (13, 0.03796821181062157), (1, 0.03777621092166489), 
... (3, 0.02907007584458954), (5, 0.027577126778171947)], 
... [(6, 0.24885153810452418), (13, 0.11945937235381485), 
... (1, 0.07967490411502279), (7, 0.059837943219436064), 
... (11, 0.054917316390175455), (3, 0.05439173103552319), 
... (12, 0.042902668032641526), (2, 0.04067120278932331)]]
>>> [sorted(sublist) for sublist in raw]
[[(1, 0.03777621092166489), (3, 0.02907007584458954), (5, 0.027577126778171947), (8, 0.44880571384598744), (13, 0.03796821181062157), (17, 0.0403732344197908)], [(1, 0.07967490411502279), (2, 0.04067120278932331), (3, 0.05439173103552319), (6, 0.24885153810452418), (7, 0.059837943219436064), (11, 0.054917316390175455), (12, 0.042902668032641526), (13, 0.11945937235381485)]]
```

Or to do it in-place:

```
for sublist in raw: sublist.sort()
```

Answer (score 2):

if you do not want to sort the entire `raw` list you can use:

```
list(map(sorted, raw)
```

Comment: Ok great, This is better than the other answer using `list(map(` since you avoid the use of unneeded `lambda`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda function instead:

```
print(list(map(lambda x:sorted(x), raw)))
```

output :

```
[[(1, 0.03777621092166489), (3, 0.02907007584458954), (5, 0.027577126778171947), (8, 0.44880571384598744), (13, 0.03796821181062157), (17, 0.0403732344197908)], [(1, 0.07967490411502279), (2, 0.04067120278932331), (3, 0.05439173103552319), (6, 0.24885153810452418), (7, 0.059837943219436064), (11, 0.054917316390175455), (12, 0.042902668032641526), (13, 0.11945937235381485)]]
```